# Querying all the records based on multiple combo boxes from a form, in MS Access

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Please help me solve this. I have 2 combo boxes (Function Name & Year). I would like to query the results based on those combo boxes and if those boxes are left empty, all the records to be displayed. I have used the below code and it is working only for 1 combo box:

`=[Forms]![YourForm]![YourCombo] OR [Forms]![YourForm]![YourCombo] IS NULL`

When I apply the same logic for the 2nd Combobox, the results are not showing up. Below is the code which I have used:

```
FROM Master_DataBase
WHERE (((Master_DataBase.Status_of_Project)="Completed"))
GROUP BY Master_DataBase.Function, Master_DataBase.Project_Name, Year([Project_Start_Date])
HAVING (((Master_DataBase.Function)=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction]) Is Null)) AND
(((Master_DataBase.Function)=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear]) Is Null))
ORDER BY Count(Master_DataBase.Status_of_Project) DESC;
```

I have attached the form combo box image for your reference.

[image]

Attached one more (Design View) for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by fixing your error:

HAVING (((Master_DataBase.Function)=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction]) Is Null)) AND
(((Master_DataBase.Function)=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear]) Is Null))

to

HAVING (((Master_DataBase.Function)=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction]) Is Null)) AND
(((**Year(Master_DataBase.Project_Start_Date**))=[Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear])) OR ((([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear]) Is Null))

Edit:

I would just simplify the whole expression to:

```
HAVING Master_DataBase.Function=Nz([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyFunction],Master_DataBase.Function)
AND Year(Master_DataBase.Project_Start_Date)=Nz([Forms]![Navigator_Form]![FilterbyYear],Year(Master_DataBase.Project_Start_Date))
```

Comment: it's asking `Master_Database.Year` as a parameter, and however, it is not showing the exact results.

Comment: Is your table field actually called `Year`? That was just an example. You have to use whatever field `FilterbyYear` is supposed to be comparing against.

Comment: I have attached the Design View image for your reference. Actually, the field name is Project_Start_Date. I have used Year formula for that.

Comment: Take a look at my edited example. I may have missed a parenthesis, it is hard to judge on the SO editor but that should get you close enough.

Comment: It is considering the Function Combo box Results, but not the Year Combo box.

Comment: I added a much more straightforward version for the `HAVING` part of the expression.

Comment: Make sure you do not let the GUI designer edit your SQL code after you have manually edit it. It will just break it.

Comment: The edit is working perfectly now, thank you :)